# Upgrading Apache HTTP Server 2.4.7 to 2.4.10-2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, apache2

Help me to upgrade my apache , there is a security issue 2.4.7

Apache HTTP Server Request
 Smuggling Vulnerability via
 Invalid Chunk-Extension
Characters, CVE-2015-3183

I tried to upgrade and update still seems 2.4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. As [the Ubuntu CVE tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2015/CVE-2015-3183.html) shows, the Apache package in 14.04 has been patched:

```
Upstream                                released (2.4.16)
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)     released (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)          released (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5)
Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)             released (2.4.10-9ubuntu1.1)
Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)            released (2.4.12-2ubuntu2)
```

Related:

- Corresponding [Ubuntu Security Notice](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2686-1/)

Comment: am pretty new to this , can you guide me what need to be done to upgrade apache

Comment: Read the first sentence: You don't need to upgrade to 2.4.10.

Comment: so what is the solution for the "Vulnerability" , is there anything we can do to overcome this issue

Comment: The vulnerability has been patched. You have said you have installed the latest version from the repositories. That is all that you need to do.

Comment: thanks for your comments. From my understanding , the fix is available in the default repository, and when we try to update this will be reflect to the apache in our server .Please correct me if am wrong. I didnt said installed latest version , installation done a year back.I tried to upgrade and update.

Comment: Yes. Run `apt-cache policy apache2`. If the version marked with stars is the version mentioned above or newer, you are safe from this CVE.

Comment: *** 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8 0 this is what my version is. So we are safe is it?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, the CVE was patched in 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5. So you have a newer release and are safe from that CVE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33424/discussion-between-seetha-raman-and-muru).